# Passing data between WPF and class

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm facing a problem where I don't know on how to implement the WPF. I admit to be pretty new to WPF.

I got a complex project which I abstract here a lot. The project is to manage a lot of different usb devices. This device are managed within one class ("manager-class") which handles connecting, disconnecting, settings for the devices, receiving data and more automated routines.

I created a WPF but I'm not sure on how to get the data into the WPF as a lot of things (connecting/disconnecting/updates) I need to show live on the WPF. I started by creating some dockpanels within the C#-code of the WPF. This works in order to build up the startup structure. The problem I'm facing is to send a signal to the WPF that "manager-class" got updated and I also have to update the WPF (add panels, set checkboxes etc.).

I appreciate any hint as I don't really have starting point to implement this.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look (google or bing) at databinding,INotifyPropertyChanged and observable objects and collections in context with WPF. You'll find tons...
Here is a example of simple data binding http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wpfsdk/archive/2006/10/19/wpf-basic-data-binding-faq.aspx

When you feel save enough with this I would suggest to research for MVVM. This pattern helps a lot in XAML based languages to structure and seperate concerns of your code...

HTH

Comment: Glad you like it. Sorry I could not go more in detail because your question for so general. It's a huge topic. If it helped please check as answered outherwise provide more detail to your question, thanks.